# HTML class isn't getting added dynamically at runtime (Blazor)

Tags: html, .net, blazor

I am trying to hide/show a spinner component I made at runtime in Blazor. However, it's not showing up, despite Show() getting called successfully (verified by breakpoint). In the browser, I see that the `show` class isn't getting added to the element at all.

My code:

```
<div class="loading-indicator @(Display? "show" : String.Empty)">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="spinner-border loading-indicator-spinner text-light" role="status"></div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    
    public bool Display;

    public void Show()
    {
        Display = true;
    }

    public void Hide()
    {
        Display = false;
    }
}
```

I also tried surrounding everything in an `@if(Display) { ... }` code block, but that's not working either.

Comment: how are you triggering the `Show` and `Hide` functions?

Comment: as you can see in this snippet its working https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/wHkZwKvz52dViNR132  so its most likely an issue with how you're calling those functions.

Comment: @RBee Literally just this inside of OnInitializedAsync(): `SpinnerOverlay.Show();`
Edit: As I mentioned above as well, I am hitting breakpoints that I place inside the Show() and Hide() methods and seeing Display get set accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand, can you update the question with your current code that is not working. Specifically how the Show and Hide functions are being called.

Comment: Is this component a child of another component and you're manually calling the @ref function?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments sounds like you're using the reference `@ref` of the component to call the child function. If that's the case then you need to add `StateHasChanged()` in your Show/Hide methods.

`Child.razor`

```
<div class="loading-indicator @(Display? "show" : String.Empty)">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="spinner-border loading-indicator-spinner text-light" role="status"></div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    public bool Display;
    public void Show()
    {
        Display = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    public void Hide()
    {
        Display = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

[Snippet](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/wRujmUvC09mBWEG833)